# SQL to pull duplicated data from one column or another

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been struggling with creating an SQL script in Access that will pull some columns from a table if the data is duplicated in one column or another. My example table looks like this:

| title | MAC | Online | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PC1 | ab-bc-cd-ef-12 | Online | Today |
| PC2 | ab-bc-cd-ef-12 | Offline | Yesterday |
| PC1 | ab-bc-89-c5-78 | Offline | 1 year |
| PC4 | a6-65-bf-33-01 | Online | Today |

and I'm trying to get an output similar to:

| title | MAC | Online | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PC1 | ab-bc-cd-ef-12 | Online | Today |
| PC2 | ab-bc-cd-ef-12 | Offline | Yesterday |
| PC1 | ab-bc-89-c5-78 | Offline | 1 year |

I have put together this SQL so far:

```
select
    s.title,
    MAC,
    time,
    online
FROM
    Table1 AS s
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT title FROM Table1 GROUP BY title HAVING count(*) > 1) AS t
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAC FROM Table1 GROUP BY MAC HAVING count(*) > 1) AS u ON
        s.title = t.title AND s.MAC = u.MAC
```

Running it however bring up there is a Syntax error in the FROM clause. I have tried adding the parenthesis into the inital FROM statement like:

```
select
    s.title,
    MAC,
    time,
    online
FROM
    (
        (
            Table1 AS s
            INNER JOIN ( SELECT title FROM Table1 GROUP BY title HAVING count(*) > 1 ) AS t
        )
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT MAC FROM Table1 GROUP BY MAC HAVING count(*) > 1
        ) AS u 
            ON s.title = t.title AND s.MAC = u.MAC
```

Anywhere I add further parenthesis will highlight it as the error when I try to run it, but removing them highlights the second `JOIN` statement as the error.

I'm sure there are probably other errors in the code or even a better way to write this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The tables looks great in the preview for the post, but does not look good after submitting, is that just me?

Comment: It's a bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358999/markdown-preview-doesnt-match-post https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371475/some-markdown-tables-incorrectly-omit-an-entire-column-in-the-rendered-post-but https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359192/markdown-table-preview-does-not-detect-missing-blank-line-before-table-header

Comment: What is the purpose of your subqueries? And you need to specify a JOIN `ON` condition for every `JOIN`, but you've only specified one.

Comment: Please explain why PC4 should be excluded from the output, and why PC1 should be mentioned twice.

Comment: Use query designer to build query objects for inner queries. Then build outer query using other query objects. This will get you correct syntax. Then switch to SQLView to copy/paste inner query SQL statements to build nested all-in-one. The resultant output is only the PC2 record. Need to clarify rules for achieving desired output.

Comment: Sorry. I'm trying to get a returned table that shows if there is a duplicate entry in one column or another column. In this case, PC1 has a duplicate title with another record with PC1 as a title. I would also like it to return if the MAC address is duplicated without the title being a duplicate as well. Since PC4 has neither a duplicate MAC or title, it can be omitted from the final table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this union query.

```
SELECT tblDuplicate.Title, tblDuplicate.MAC, tblDuplicate.Online, tblDuplicate.OnlineTime FROM tblDuplicate INNER JOIN (SELECT tblDuplicate.Title, Count(tblDuplicate.Title) AS CountOfTitle FROM tblDuplicate GROUP BY tblDuplicate.Title HAVING (((Count(tblDuplicate.Title))>1))) as t1 ON tblDuplicate.Title = t1.Title;
    union
SELECT tblDuplicate.Title, tblDuplicate.MAC, tblDuplicate.Online, tblDuplicate.OnlineTime FROM tblDuplicate INNER JOIN (SELECT tblDuplicate.MAC, Count(tblDuplicate.MAC) AS CountOfMAC FROM tblDuplicate GROUP BY tblDuplicate.MAC HAVING (((Count(tblDuplicate.MAC))>1))) as t2 ON tblDuplicate.MAC = t2.MAC;
```

Comment: As per OP's desired output, it seems OP wants both title and MAC as duplicate. If he wants only MAC as duplicate then qry will return only one record.

Answer (score 0):

So this is kinda working:

```
SELECT s.Name, s.[MAC Addresses], s.[Offline Date], s.state
  FROM Table1 AS s 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT name FROM Table1 GROUP BY name HAVING count(*) > 1)  AS t ON s.name = t.name 
UNION ALL 
  SELECT s.Name, s.[MAC Addresses], s.[Offline Date], s.state
  FROM Table1 AS s 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT [MAC Addresses] FROM Table1 GROUP BY [MAC Addresses] HAVING count(*) > 1) AS u ON s.[MAC Addresses] = u.[MAC Addresses];
```

Apologies for the change in record names. I was running these tests on a separate test table than before with my actual imported data.

The output of this table is a little messy as it puts in both tables mashed together and if 2 records are almost exact duplicates, then it might be a bit hard to read. I believe it is robust enough to handle if only one column is duplicated at all. I'll try to run this on a larger set of tables with production data to check.